# $\operatorname{tr}((1 -\varepsilon)^A)= \operatorname{tr}(A)$?

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

Let $\varepsilon \geq 0 $ for matrices $A \in\mathbb R^{n \times n}$

$$\operatorname{tr}((1 -\varepsilon)^A)= \operatorname{tr}(A) \text{ ?}$$

where $(1 -\varepsilon)^A = e^{\log(1-\varepsilon)\cdot A}$
how to see that ?

Comment: Why does the right-hand side not depend on $\epsilon$?

Comment: Is $tr((1 -\epsilon)^A)$ or $\text{det}((1 -\epsilon)^A)$?

Comment: @angryavian https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2011/EECS-2011-56.pdf see page 13 of this one

Comment: @J.rafa   www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2011/EECS-2011-56.pdf see page 13 of this one

Comment: Is $\varepsilon^2$ supposed to be $0$ ?

Comment: This isn't true when $A$ is the identity matrix.